# Json table update after certain date

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

At the moment i have this code

```
// JavaScript Document

   $.ajax({

      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',

      url: 'https://api.import.io/store/data/93296dfc-1edb-4aa6-a3e5-2207fa52f3ea/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seatwave.com%2Fthe-script-tickets%2Fseason&_user=687c839c-f236-4817-90c9-f6eb81334c2a&_apikey=pvXHYMTbZD3Za3TB%2Bn8LgVybPltV1a379yBNfSfzepw2piIhs%2FxHinVseH7G4BwItVQ57aNJnyk6g6g%2BAxyEMg%3D%3D',

      success: function (json) {
           //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
           for(var i =0;i < json.results.length;i++) {
             var title = json.results[i].name;
             var venue = json.results[i].venue;
                 var date = json.results[i].date;
                    var button = "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='"+(i+1)+".html'>Compare</button>";

             $("#apple").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+venue+"</td><td>"+date+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
$("#apple").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function(){
   location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
});
           }
     },
     error: function(error){
          console.log(error);
     }
   });
```

This appends the URL to a table. However as you can see this code here `data-url='"+(i+1)+".html'` created the button with an increment of 1 on the amount of buttons listed.

The issue is, this api is updating every 5 hours. When the event passes, The buttons need to really be updated. Otherwise the whole site breaks.

So the question is how could i go around making the links unique and update when an event passes? whilst im writing this i believe i could just use the Date function, So the code would be

`data-url='"+date+".html'`

Any other suggestions would be great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could do this. The easiest would be to add a [meta tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to the page that forces it to refresh each 5 hours. If for some reason you need to do it with code, then you'll need to add a timer that checks for updates and refreshes the button data.  A working example of that is shown below. The data does have a time stamp, but it's set to the far future. So rather than check that the code simply updates each 10 seconds (you can set to whatever frequency you need).

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <style type="text/css">
      table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;}
      table td { border: 1px gray dotted; padding: 2px;background-color:aliceblue;}
      table caption {font-weight: bold; color: firebrick;}
    </style>
    
    <table id="apple"><caption></caption><tbody></tbody></table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  var lastUpdate;
  
  function update() {

   $.ajax({

      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',

      url: 'https://api.import.io/store/data/93296dfc-1edb-4aa6-a3e5-2207fa52f3ea/_query?input/webpage/url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seatwave.com%2Fthe-script-tickets%2Fseason&_user=687c839c-f236-4817-90c9-f6eb81334c2a&_apikey=pvXHYMTbZD3Za3TB%2Bn8LgVybPltV1a379yBNfSfzepw2piIhs%2FxHinVseH7G4BwItVQ57aNJnyk6g6g%2BAxyEMg%3D%3D',

      success: function (json) {
        
          /*
            Removed - data time stamp does not appear to be useful
            if (json.results[0].date == lastUpdate) return;
            lastUpdate = json.results[0].date;
            $("#apple caption").html( 'Last Updated: ' + lastUpdate );
          */
        
           $("#apple caption").html( "Last Updated: " + (new Date()).toString() );
        
           $("#apple tbody").html( "" );

        for(var i =0;i < json.results.length;i++) {
             var title = json.results[i].name;
             var venue = json.results[i].venue;
                 var date = json.results[i].date;
             
             var button = "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='"+(i+1)+".html'>Compare</button>";

             $("#apple tbody").append("<tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+venue+"</td><td>"+date+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr>");
$("#apple").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function(){
   location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
});
           }
     },
     error: function(error){
          console.log(error);
     }
   });
    
    
}
  
  update();
  
  var timerId = setInterval( update, 10000 );
  
  
</script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```